# CRM 2013 online Subgrid implementation best practice

Tags: dynamics-crm

I'm new to CRM, and am having difficulties implementing a subgrid onto an account form.  I am not a programmer.

I will not bore you with the methods that I have tried to so far; that could take a while.  Suffice it to say, I am having no luck.

i have created and imported two sets of records from my SQL database.  One set was imported into the standard Accounts entity and the other was imported into a custom entity; let's just call that it Problems.

The relationship between Accounts to Problems is one-to-many.  Each Account has a "problemID" and each related Problem has a "problemID" as well.

I need to be able to place a subgrid containing all related Problems onto the Accounts forms.  I need to be able to see the old ones and create new ones.

How would YOU handle this? 
Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For a 1:N relationship between Accounts and Problems you only need a lookup to the Account Entity on the Problem entity. Then you can:

1. Edit the Account Form
2. Insert a Sub-grid
3. Set the sub-grid to look to "Only Related Records" for "Problems" 
   [image]